# Blurred reflection of the broadcast on the background

Tags: java, bitmap, exoplayer, rtmp

I'm making an app similar to Rave. The point of it is to watch videos together. As in the original app, I would like to create a reflection of the broadcast on the background, as shown in the picture.

I implemented it like this:

1. I take the Bitmap from my textureView where the broadcast is shown(60fps):

   ```
   Bitmap frameBitmap = textureView.getBitmap();
   ```
2. I make a blurred Bitmap with the RenderScript Intrinsics Replacement Toolkit:

   ```
   Bitmap blurredBitmap = Toolkit.INSTANCE.blur(frameBitmap, 25);
   ```
3. I adjust the blurred size of the Bitmap to the width and height I want:

   ```
   Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width-
   top_W, height-top_H, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
   Canvas canvas = new Canvas(croppedBitmap);
   canvas.drawBitmap(frameBitmap, (int)(- 
   croppedBitmap.getWidth()*1.5), -top_H, null);
   ```
4. I set the background:

   ```
   BG_View.setBackground(new 
   BitmapDrawable(getResources(), croppedBitmap));
   ```

Everything is cool, except that the background lags behind the broadcast by some fractions of a second. I really want to implement instant reflection, but I don't understand how to do it otherwise at all.(Without blurring reflection also lags behind translation).

[image]